# MySQL: Show or not depending on field & reference count comparison

Tags: mysql, database, count, left-join, where-clause

I'll try to be brief. I have a table with "Guests" and a table with "Rooms". Every Guest can be assigned a single room, but the rooms themselves have varying amount of guests they can hold, specified in a field "Space". In a form used to register a new guest, I'd like to create a list of available rooms to pick from - one that shows only the numbers of rooms that can still fit at least one person.

My idea was to simply use:

```
SELECT Rooms.Number
FROM Rooms
LEFT OUTER JOIN Guests ON Rooms.ID = Guests.Room
WHERE COUNT(Guests.Room) < Rooms.Space
ORDER BY Rooms.Number
```

But that is not working. I thought maybe comparing two fields is the problem, so I also tried a WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE (Rooms.Space - COUNT(Guests.Room)) > 0
```

But this one also returns an error.

I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Hi. You probably want to rent rooms when the spaces are >= the occupants. Please read & act on [mcve]. Read a SQL manual/intro re how count, and hence group by (implicit & explicit), work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Rooms.Number
FROM Rooms
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) from GUESTS WHERE Guests.Room=Rooms.ID) < Rooms.Space
ORDER BY Rooms.Number
```

Seems clearer

```
SELECT Rooms.Number
FROM Rooms
LEFT OUTER JOIN Guests ON Rooms.ID = Guests.Room
GROUP BY Rooms.Number
HAVING COUNT(Guests.Room) < MAX(Rooms.Space)
ORDER BY Rooms.Number
```

Would probably also work

Comment: The first solution worked, thanks! It was simpler than I thought, which is usually the case with solutions to seemingly impossible problems ^^

Comment: Actually, hold up. The first solution seems to ignore the room number. I put two guests in one room and all two-people rooms disappeared from the lists, despite being empty.

Comment: It should probably be RoomNumber instead of ID but I don't know your schema.  You should be able to make it work from here.  Feel free to edit the answer when you do.

Comment: The second piece of code removes all single-person rooms from the list (empty ones) unless  I change the > to a >=, meaning COUNT seems to always result in at least 1, not a 0.

Comment: Yes you are correct about the second one.  There will always count 1 (the room row). I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out I had to change COUNT(*) to COUNT(Guests.Room) on the second one. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an aggregation function like `Count()` without `Group By` clause, it will compute the aggregate value over the complete dataset. Instead, use `Group by` on `Rooms.Number` with `Having` clause to filter out the Rooms with available space.

Try:

```
SELECT Rooms.Number, 
       Rooms.Space - COUNT(Guests.Room) AS available_space 
FROM Rooms
LEFT OUTER JOIN Guests ON Rooms.ID = Guests.Room
GROUP BY Rooms.Number, Rooms.Space 
HAVING available_space > 0
ORDER BY Rooms.Number
```

Comment: It results in a `Not in aggregate function or group by clause: org.hsqldb.Expression@7227722d` error

Comment: @eworm can u check the updated answer now. You have `only_full_group_by` mode on. It should work now.

Comment: Still doesn't work for some reason. I tried adding everything to the GROUP BY clause...

Comment: @eworm This really does not make sense. Definitely some silly error, or some strict sql settings (although I now have ansi compliant group by). Nevertheless you got the answer already I think. good luck :)